# How to start Activity once and then use the same instance?

Tags: android

I have the `Activity` with Messages list. When new message arrived I want to show it in the list. And I want to use the same `Activity` instance instead of creating new for each new message.

But my Activity doesn't opening (and I don't see my log message from `onCreate()` method).

There is me `Activity` code:

```
public class MessagesListDialogActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e("MESSAGE", "onCreate()");

    // ... create UI
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    // obtain the message and add to list on UI
}
```

}

And this is code from my `Launcher` class:

```
public static void showMessage(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Message message) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessagesListDialogActivity.class);
    BundleUtil.setMessage(intent, message);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this lines from `Manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".features.messages.list.MessagesListDialogActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

I try use different launchMode params, like **singleTask** and **singleInstance** but it doesn't work.

Comment: where you are calling `showMessage`?

Comment: @Sree from separate class (XML parser) and Context i get from Application

Comment: Sometimes the context may be missing, debug your code and find what is happening.

Comment: @Sree ok, bu there isn't null instead Context

Comment: maybe not null, a wrong contact. Check once again

Comment: If you set MessagesListDialogActivity singleTop. when MessagesListDialogActivity  exists in your stack, onCreate won't be called,  use onNewIntent.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention. After lot of attempts to fix it i try use this flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

And this help me. Thank you and hope my experience help you in the future.